# Sampling in stages in R

Tags: r, sampling

I am running some sampling simulations from census data and I would like to sample in 2 stages.

- First I want to sample 25 households within each village.
- Second I want to sample 1 person from each household.

My data is in long format, with a village identifier, a household identifier, and a binary disease status (`0 = healthy`, `1 = diseased`). The following code runs a *monte-carlo simulation* to sample 25 individuals per village 3000 times and record the number of malaria-positive individuals sampled.

But, I would like to sample 1 individual from 25 sampled households from each village. I can't figure it out.

[Here is the link to my data:](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gmb46wj4fw4tk2c/sampling%20data.txt)

```
d = read.table("data.txt", sep=",", header=TRUE)
villages = split(d$malaria, d$villageid)
positives = vector("list", 3000)
for(i in 1:3000) {
    sampled = lapply(villages, sample, 25)
    positives[[i]] = lapply(sampled, sum)
}
```

Comment: sure, but it would be easier to show you if you provide sample data. :)

Comment: I just updated it - should I include a link to my data or would this be enough to go from?

Comment: I just updated again.

Comment: Nice, if there's no answer provided in next 12 hours, I'll try (have to sleep now).

Comment: The 1 sample from 25 sampled villages, is it the same for each of the 25? Or you need 1 drawn out for each of the 25 villages? Then, shouldn't you be accounting the "size" of each village?? That is, in the first case, your sample can only be <= minimum village size amongst the 25 sampled.. right? Care to elaborate?

Comment: I don't want to account for the relative size of each village (the minimum number of households in each village in the dataset is 30).  There are 177 villages I believe - I want to sample 25 households from each and every village.  I then want to sample 1 person from each household sampled.  Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a workaround.  It is quite convoluted and involves taking the data and creating another dataset.  (I did this in Stata as my R capabilities are limited.)  First I sort the dataset by house number and load that into R (d.people).  Then I create a new dataset by collapsing the old dataset by house number, and load that into R (d.house).  I do the sampling in 2 stages, first sampling 1 person from each household in the people dataset.  I can then sample 25 "household sampled people" from each village after combining the houses dataset with the output from sampling 1 person from each household.

```
d.people = read.table("people data", sep=",", header=TRUE)
d.houses = read.table("houses data", sep=",", header=TRUE)

for(i in 1:3000){
    houses = split(d.people$malaria, d.people$house)
    firststage = sapply(houses, sample, 1)
    secondstage = cbind(d.houses, firststage)
    villages = split(secondstage$firststage, secondstage$village)
    sampled = lapply(villages, sample, 25)
    positives[[i]] = lapply(sampled, sum)
    }
```

Comment: But you're doing the second step first here.

Comment: I'm okay with that.  It gets me what I want.  It is still a 2-stage sample, with 25 households sampled and 1 person sampled from each sampled household.

Comment: I am glad it gets you the right solution. But it does matter if you provide us with the right data/method and *explain correctly*. You're using two data sets here as well and binding the 2nd data.

Comment: I derived the second dataset from the data I posted. What part did I not explain correctly?

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
replicate(3000, sum(sapply(lapply(villages, sample, 25), sample, 1)))
```

> lapply(villages, sample, 25) -> gives 25 households for all 177 villages
>   sapply(., sample, 1) -> sample 1 person from these 25 people from each of 177 villages
>   sum(.) -> sum the sampled values
>   replicate -> repeat the same function 3000 times

Comment: I don't think that does it either.  Thank you though.

Comment: how do you mean? please elaborate.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what it does, but when I ran the "sum(sapply(lapply(villages, sample, 25), sample, 1))" portion of the code I got the result of "9".  To me that suggests that it drew a single sample rather than a sample for each village.

Comment: +1 This is a valid solution (if I correctly understood the question).

Comment: @SvenHohenstein, I think that's the problem.

Comment: @SvenHohenstein.  The first line samples individuals from villages, not households from villages.  I need to sample 25 households from villages, and 1 person from those 25 sampled households.

Comment: @David This task is impossible. You cannot sample 25 different households from each village. Try this command: `sapply(split(d$house, d$village), function(x) length(unique(x)))`. It returns the number of different households for each village. The majority of these numbers is smaller than 25.

Comment: @Sven.  I found a work around it by splitting my datasets as I showed in my answer.  I couldn't find a solution with the sapply either, and it was only after seeing the responses here that I figured out how to do it..